# PDO connecting to remote MySQL db

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, pdo

I'm trying to connect to a remote MySQL db using PHP. It was supposed to be an easy task but cause I'm a newbie in PHP it's going bad. I got a key-cert.pem, a client-cert.pem, host name and credentials. I copy one of the examples around the web and this is what I did:

```
pdoDb = new PDO(
  'mysql:host=customer_host_name;dbname=customer_db_name', 
  'my_username', 
  'my_password', 
  array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY=>'C:/Apache24/htdocs/PETALO/lib/client-key.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT=>'C:/Apache24/htdocs/PETALO/lib/client-cert.pem'
  ));
```

When I execute this code I got this error back:

```
Warning: PDO::__construct(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto in C:\Apache24\htdocs\custo\lib\database.php on line 16

Warning: PDO::__construct(): Cannot connect to MySQL by using SSL in C:\Apache24\htdocs\custo\lib\database.php on line 16

Warning: PDO::__construct(): [2002] (trying to connect via tcp://customer_host_name:3306) in C:\Apache24\htdocs\custo\lib\database.php on line 16
error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
```

Customer doesn't give me a `ca-cert.pem` and credentials are correct. What am I missing?

Comment: `Customer doesn't give me a ca-cert.pem` ... meaning this is a cert they signed themselves rather than got from a CA??

Comment: Yes they signed themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning has nothing to do with any of the certificate files. Either OpenSSL is not enabled in the php.ini configuration file, or your php version was not compiled with SSL support at all, or the mysql driver / php you use has a bug, like [php bug #55870](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55870). Certificates and mysql settings will only come into play after PDO tries to initiate a connection over SSL.